# Swaggydoc Plugin grails 3.2.1

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, swagger, swagger-ui

I am running grails 3.2.1 and want to create Swagger-documentation for my REST endpoints. I added the SwaggyDoc-plugin to the dependencies in my build.gradle script by adding:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:swaggydoc-grails3:0.28.0"
```

And configure it by `https://rahulsom.github.io/swaggydoc/` .

In IntelliJ I see the Swaggydoc-dependency added to my list of libraries.

After starting my Grails-application via the grails run-app command and opening my application by entering `http://localhost:8080/api/` I get an swagger-ui index.html, but I find error in console log(see in image).

[console log errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc6qC.png)

And this exceptions in grails.

```
ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[Digest Input Stream] MD5 Message Digest from SUN
```

Comment: Have you looked at [springfox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-grails-integration)? If not would love to get your feedback on it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 
When we create grails application inside intellij we will get the following dependency inside `application.yaml` file.

```
runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.11.6"
```

We need to replace this with the following :

```
runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"
```

This error will be resolved.